# Jetpack Compose inner shadow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to create an inner shadow with Jetpack Compose? The gradient should run from black on the outside to transparent on the inside. `Modifier.shadow()` is just for outer shadows. Using negative elevation is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
fun Modifier.innerShadow(
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    cornersRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    spread: Dp = 0.dp,
    blur: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetY: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetX: Dp = 0.dp
) = drawWithContent {

    drawContent()

    val rect = Rect(Offset.Zero, size)
    val paint = Paint()

    drawIntoCanvas {

        paint.color = color
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        it.saveLayer(rect, paint)
        it.drawRoundRect(
            left = rect.left,
            top = rect.top,
            right = rect.right,
            bottom = rect.bottom,
            cornersRadius.toPx(),
            cornersRadius.toPx(),
            paint
         )
         val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
         frameworkPaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT)
         if (blur.toPx() > 0) {
             frameworkPaint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(blur.toPx(), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
         }
         val left = if (offsetX > 0.dp) {
             rect.left + offsetX.toPx()
         } else {
             rect.left
         }
         val top = if (offsetY > 0.dp) {
             rect.top + offsetY.toPx()
         } else {
             rect.top
         }
         val right = if (offsetX < 0.dp) {
             rect.right + offsetX.toPx()
         } else {
             rect.right
         }
         val bottom = if (offsetY < 0.dp) {
             rect.bottom + offsetY.toPx()
         } else {
             rect.bottom
         }
         paint.color = Color.Black
         it.drawRoundRect(
             left = left + spread.toPx() / 2,
             top = top + spread.toPx() / 2,
             right = right - spread.toPx() / 2,
             bottom = bottom - spread.toPx() / 2,
             cornersRadius.toPx(),
             cornersRadius.toPx(),
             paint
         )
         frameworkPaint.xfermode = null
         frameworkPaint.maskFilter = null
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(240.dp)
        .height(180.dp)
        .outerShadow(
            color = Color(0xff000000),
            alpha = 0.5f,
            cornersRadius = 20.dp,
            shadowBlurRadius = 30.dp,
            offsetX = 0.dp,
            offsetY = 15.dp
        )
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
        .background(Color(0xFF282A2F))
        .innerShadow(
            blur = 1.dp,
            color = Color(0xff00FFFF),
            cornersRadius = 20.dp,
            offsetX = (-40.5).dp,
            offsetY = (-10.5).dp
        )
        .innerShadow(
            blur = 20.dp,
            color = Color(0xffff0000),
            cornersRadius = 20.dp,
            offsetX = 0.5.dp,
            offsetY = 0.5.dp
        )
        .padding(14.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.notification_service),
        modifier = Modifier,
        color = Color.White
     )
}
```

I hope it helps.
`outerShadow` is custom modifier too, copied from other websites.

Comment: Works well. Thanks!

Comment: could you please add some link of outerShadow， I really need that.

Comment: For outer shadow check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqvaiNmVIaI Sample code: https://github.com/Debdutta-Panda/CustomShadow

Answer (score 8):

Position of `Modifier.shadow` relative to Modifier.background places shadow inside your component. Also you can create Modifier.drawWithContent and frameworkPaint a show with blur.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(20.dp)
) {
    ComponentWithInnerShadow()
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
    ComponentWithOuterShadow()
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
    ComponentWithCustomInnerShadow()
}

@Composable private fun ComponentWithInnerShadow() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .shadow(2.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello World", modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp))
    } }

@Composable
private fun ComponentWithOuterShadow() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .shadow(2.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .background(Color.Yellow)

    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello World", modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
private  fun ComponentWithCustomInnerShadow() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.innerShadow()

    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello World", modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp))
    }
}
```

And with composed modifier. I didn't set parameters just set arbitrary numbers you can set your own parameters, and set color if you want to. This one looks better than standard inner shadow though. You need to provide color for foreground and shape with this one either. I set color and drew Rounded rectangle for demonstration

```
fun Modifier.innerShadow() = composed(
    inspectorInfo = {

    },
    factory = {

        val paint = remember() {
            Paint()
        }

        val foregroundPaint = remember() {
            Paint().apply {
                color = Color.Yellow
            }
        }

        val frameworkPaint = remember {
            paint.asFrameworkPaint()
        }

        Modifier.drawWithContent {
            this.drawIntoCanvas {
                val color = Color.LightGray

                val radius = 2.dp.toPx()

                val shadowColor = color
                    .copy(alpha = .7f)
                    .toArgb()
                val transparent = color
                    .copy(alpha = 0f)
                    .toArgb()

                frameworkPaint.color = transparent

                frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
                    radius,
                    0f,
                    0f,
                    shadowColor
                )
                val shadowRadius = 4.dp.toPx()

                it.drawRoundRect(
                    left = 0f,
                    top = 0f,
                    right = this.size.width,
                    bottom = this.size.height,
                    radiusX = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    radiusY = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    paint = foregroundPaint
                )

                it.drawRoundRect(
                    left = 0f,
                    top = 0f,
                    right = this.size.width,
                    bottom = this.size.height,
                    radiusX = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    radiusY = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    paint = paint
                )

                it.drawRoundRect(
                    left = shadowRadius,
                    top = shadowRadius,
                    right = this.size.width - shadowRadius,
                    bottom = this.size.height - shadowRadius,
                    radiusX = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    radiusY = 5.dp.toPx(),
                    paint = foregroundPaint
                )
                drawContent()

            }
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the gradient should be transparent towards the middle.

Comment: `frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer` sets shadow position and blur not gradient and it's generally used for drawing shadow, i use it to draw colored shadow as you can see [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/ComposeBadge). You need to play with those values or you can draw gradient instead of `drawRoundRect(paint = paint ) `

Comment: i posted last one as demonstration with arbitrary numbers to show how to use blur, composed and drawing custom shapes. `setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy)` radius changes radius of blur, dx when positive sets shadow to right, and dy to down

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported but you have alternative options:

1. Use a border modifier with a gradient brush
2. Use Android Canvas
3. Use a gradient and `Modifier.drawBehind` to draw the inset shadow underneath the content

[Source](https://app.slack.com/client/T09229ZC6/CJLTWPH7S/thread/CJLTWPH7S-1637513630.271700)